# Custom Engineering VKP80 - print on linux is not printing anything at all

Tags: linux, ubuntu, printing, driver, cups

Why Linux cant print to the printer model: `Custom Engineering VKP80` ?

[image]

```
$ lpstat -p -d
printer CUSTOM_Engineering_VKP80 is idle.  enabled since Sat 05 Apr 2014 10:50:52 PM CEST
printer LabelWriter-450 is idle.  enabled since Tue 25 Mar 2014 10:47:06 AM CET
printer PDF is idle.  enabled since Tue 25 Mar 2014 10:40:12 AM CET
printer Zebra_TLP2844 is idle.  enabled since Tue 25 Mar 2014 05:52:37 AM CET
system default destination: LabelWriter-450

$ echo 'test' > /tmp/test.txt
$ lpr -P CUSTOM_Engineering_VKP80 /tmp/test.txt
```

Nothing happens.

***EDIT:***

```
E [05/Apr/2014:22:49:07 +0200] [Client 17] Empty Basic password.
E [05/Apr/2014:22:49:12 +0200] [Client 16] pam_authenticate() returned 7 (Authentication failure)
E [05/Apr/2014:22:49:20 +0200] [Client 15] pam_authenticate() returned 7 (Authentication failure)
E [05/Apr/2014:22:49:25 +0200] [Client 15] pam_authenticate() returned 7 (Authentication failure)
W [05/Apr/2014:22:50:58 +0200] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'CUSTOM_Engineering_VKP80-Gray..' already exists
E [05/Apr/2014:22:56:39 +0200] [Job 133] Aborting job because it has no files.
E [05/Apr/2014:22:57:20 +0200] [Job 134] Aborting job because it has no files.
E [05/Apr/2014:22:57:30 +0200] [Job 135] Aborting job because it has no files.
E [05/Apr/2014:22:58:08 +0200] [Job 136] Aborting job because it has no files.
E [05/Apr/2014:23:01:57 +0200] [Job 137] Stopping unresponsive job.


localhost - - [05/Apr/2014:22:50:52 +0200] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 1752 - -
localhost - sun [05/Apr/2014:22:50:52 +0200] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 1752 - -
localhost - - [05/Apr/2014:22:50:52 +0200] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 392 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - sun [05/Apr/2014:22:50:52 +0200] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 392 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - sun [05/Apr/2014:22:50:52 +0200] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 10930 - -
localhost - sun [05/Apr/2014:22:50:58 +0200] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 404 - -
localhost - - [05/Apr/2014:22:50:58 +0200] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 8463 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - sun [05/Apr/2014:22:50:58 +0200] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8463 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - sun [05/Apr/2014:22:50:58 +0200] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 2789 - -
localhost - - [05/Apr/2014:22:51:38 +0200] "POST /printers/LabelWriter-450 HTTP/1.1" 200 311 Create-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [05/Apr/2014:22:52:11 +0200] "POST /printers/LabelWriter-450 HTTP/1.1" 200 328 Create-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [05/Apr/2014:22:52:26 +0200] "POST /printers/LabelWriter-450 HTTP/1.1" 200 329 Create-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [05/Apr/2014:22:53:07 +0200] "POST /printers/CUSTOM_Engineering_VKP80 HTTP/1.1" 200 321 Create-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [05/Apr/2014:22:54:26 +0200] "POST /printers/CUSTOM_Engineering_VKP80 HTTP/1.1" 200 322 Create-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [05/Apr/2014:22:54:26 +0200] "POST /printers/CUSTOM_Engineering_VKP80 HTTP/1.1" 200 282 Send-Document successful-ok
localhost - - [05/Apr/2014:23:00:19 +0200] "POST /printers/CUSTOM_Engineering_VKP80 HTTP/1.1" 200 322 Create-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [05/Apr/2014:23:00:19 +0200] "POST /printers/CUSTOM_Engineering_VKP80 HTTP/1.1" 200 282 Send-Document successful-ok
localhost - - [05/Apr/2014:23:01:57 +0200] "POST /jobs HTTP/1.1" 200 139 Restart-Job successful-ok
localhost - sun [05/Apr/2014:23:22:28 +0200] "GET /admin/log/error_log? HTTP/1.1" 200 899 - -
```

Comment: Since you are using the CUPS printing system I suggest you take a look at its log files...

Comment: See my above EDIT for the logs, it shows everything normal but not printing at all!!!